# Will background check for a developer position ask for specific things?

Tags: developer, background-check

My manager in my old company (company A) left halfway through the time I was there and no-one really bothered to check up on my work after that. During the interview I mentioned things I got up to and so on.

Now the issue I have is that after my manager left I started doing some automated testing because I wanted to improve as a developer (the company did manual testing) and my manager never really got to see me do this. After he left, the other more experienced developers never bothered to checked my work. I've given my manager and another developer as references (company A closed down by the way). So basically no-one saw do this part of the job which I mentioned in my interview. I left because I started my Masters and I honestly don't know if anyone bothered to check my code after that.

Should I be worried if they ask my references about this part of my job? I'm not entirely sure what HR asks, but for software developer positions could it be more specific to what I done on the job?

Comment: If you could explain if asked how you went about it, what could you have opt be worried about? Besides, reference check these days tend to only confirm dates of employment. I any case, if all that you give are names and company, then they are unlikely to try too hard to find them when they learn that the company no longer exists. So, that's three reasons not to worry

Comment: This isn't what a background check usually means - a background  check is checking for any crimes jail time, details of your bank accounts and finances

Answer (score 10):

Don't raise issues that aren't there.
Don't take the initiative to point out flaws in your resume.

You will probably be asked about your resume, answer what you can and don't be afraid to say that you don't know or would have to (confirm) lookup something as you are not 100% sure. You shouldn't be worried about anything if you told the truth.

There are no rules for what HR asks you they will ask what they want to know.
I can guarantee you I haven't had any questions in any interview that were the same.
**Mainly** because I updated my resume/CV to cover such things in the future, but also because someone else might not feel it is relevant.

About your current issues explain that:

- You never got any feedback on your automated testing
- Your company didn't have rulesets for them
- None of the other developers showed any signs that they checked your code

Most of your references are to show your employee that you have been doing stuff and seeing you doing (finished) a master degree should indicate that you know what you are doing. Or at least have the capability to do a master should count for something if not more than some references that might not be able to either confirm or deny your actual work.

But above all else never lie.
It just doesn't help you and sets you off into the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what kind of background check your company is running, but i would expect them to simply ask you in person what you have done, with which techniques and tools you have worked and what conclusions you have taken.

That way they should get a way better impression of your abilities than by asking some remote guy, who might not even know what you did exactly (as is the case here).
This all assumes that there is either a technical guy present or a capable HR-person, who is not simply walking down a checklist.

You might also be able to pre-empt to a certain degree to help those questions to come up, by stating that you tried to improve your own abilities and the pre-existing processes by venturing in the field of automated testing. 
If there is a technical guy present, he will surely jump at this and ask you questions you can shine at.